# Windows Service Application Dependent that uses WINE for Linux

Tags: delphi, windows-services, delphi-xe3, wine

I am developing an custom office like application that uses a custom service that authenticates the users.

My doubts are:

1. Will it work in MAC if some client ask me to compile it to OSX using Delphi-XE3?
2. Will it work in Linux if I use WINE to port the application and the service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the VCL's `TService` framework, then it will only work on Windows, which includes use of WINE.

Comment: I did not understood. "Will work only with Windows, which **includes** use of WINE"?

Comment: To all intents and purposes, WINE is Windows. It is an implementation of Win32. But your service won't work on a Mac. You can no doubt re-use much of your code.

Comment: Am I going the wrong way here? Should I just create another executable to be run from inside my application (instead of a service) to verify if my app needs to be updated and do it? (it would be noticed only as a tray icon [or not even that])

Comment: As David said, WINE is a Win32 Emulator for running Windows executables on other platforms.  It does support the SCM API, so Windows services will run, but only within the confines of WINE, not the host Mac as a whole.

Comment: If all you need is to have your main app auto-update itself, then you do not need a service for that. Have the app check for updates periodically, such as in a background thread. If found, just download them and prompt the user for a restart. Whenever the app starts up, have it check if a downloaded update is present, and if so then install and delete it before continuing. Perform the update with a separate app only if the main app or its static dependencies need to be replaced. Detect the update, start the updater app, exit the main app, and let the updater restart the main app when ready.

Comment: Thank you for the advises. It's just because when my applications are running, I can't overwrite the executable.